# Netgear AX3000 / RAX40 detects lower bandwidth than link actually provides

Tags: home-networking, netgear-router

My home is on Verizon FiOS with 400mbps up/down. I have an Ethernet line running from the ONT to my router, and the router backfeeds all of the coax in the house through a MoCA adapter. If I connect my laptop directly to the Ethernet link and run a speed test, I’ll see about 300mbps up/down — not too far from what I’m paying for. But if I disconnect the MoCA adapter so that nothing else is attached and run a speed test from the router’s QoS interface, I’ll only get ~95mbps up/down. Does anyone know why my router thinks it only has a third of its actual available bandwidth? Are there any configurations that I should check?

Comment: What are your QoS settings?

Comment: Before I factory reset the router, QoS had been left on the default settings. Now QoS is turned off.

Comment: Is the bandwidth the same with QoS turned off?

Comment: It is. Something I've noticed in the device Statistics is that the WAN status is marked 100M/full. The original router cable is CAT 5e, and I've tried replacing it with 6A to no avail. For some reason it thinks that the WAN port only has a 100M link. So it's not a matter of the bandwidth being divided; rather it's capped at 100mbps. Not sure why yet.

Comment: Might be a problem with the router's firmware. Try to find an update for it, and if none then you might complain to Verizon Support.

Comment: I recently updated to the latest firmware. I knew I wasn't having enough fun this weekend -- I'll give Verizon a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I tried a lot of stuff. I tried updating the installing the initial release of router firmware and updated through every release that Netgear had provided. No luck. I tried unplugging the ONT BBU and disconnecting the battery terminal -- didn't help. I spent a long time contemplating the graveyard of ISP equipment and the labyrinth of coax splitters they had mounted. I chatted with Verizon support: "Your router, your problem." No help on the Netgear official support forums. No matter what I did, the WAN statistics in the admin interface read 100M (Full).

I had figured that autonegotiation was failing (the WAN port itself was immaculate), but I didn't know how to verify that (those logs aren't visible) nor test it. In the end "WAN capped at 100ms" was the magic search-engine phrase to find the solution. SNB forums provided the solution -- stick a dumb switch between the ONT and the router. The ONT negotiates with the switch, the switch negotiates with the router, et voilà. Speed's up to scratch.